# UK Foundation Licence holder use of kits

Tags: legal, united-kingdom

The terms of the foundation licence allow for use of Commercial radios and kits that conform to IR2028. IR2028 basically says that the kits must operate within amateur bands .
I cannot find any kit that conforms to IR2028.

Could an Intermediate Licence holder build a kit and have it tested by a full licence holder and then use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal answer is no.

There is one exception however, in that if the Foundation holder is directly "operating under the supervision of a Full Licence holder".  See Clause 7, para 2.76 and 2.77 of Ofcom's "Guidance for licensees" document.

You can find this document at: [Guidance for licensees](https://www.ofcom.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0026/82637/amateur_radio_licence_guidance_for_licensees.pdf)